# APP crash in debug mode but work fine in release mode on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, reactive-cocoa

APP work fine on iOS 9 and iOS 10.However,on iOS 8,it crash when run in debug mode but work fine in release mode.

**The error code is:**

```
[RACObserve(self.scrollView, contentOffset) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSInteger currentTableViewTag = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / screenWidth;
    NSLog(@"current tableView tag：%ld",(long)currentTableViewTag);
    self.currentTableView = [self viewWithTag:currentTableViewTag];
}];
```

**The console log info is:**

*-[UIScrollView rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178153f0*

**The ReactiveCocoa version is:**

```
pod 'ReactiveCocoa','~>2.1.8'
```

**My build setting is:**

[image]

**My try:**

1. Change RAC version to 2.5 but build faild.
2. Search on Google but no want answer.

**My question is:**

What's wrong with ReactiveCocoa?Why in release mode it is OK but in debug it's crash on iOS 8?

Hope someone can give an advice.

Comment: `@weakify(self);
[RACObserve(self.scrollView, contentOffset) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    @strongify(self);
    NSInteger currentTableViewTag = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / screenWidth;
    NSLog(@"current tableView tag：%ld",(long)currentTableViewTag);
    self.currentTableView = [self viewWithTag:currentTableViewTag];
}];`

Comment: Can you please try the above code?

Comment: @LalKrishna Yeah,even if I use weakSelf it crash,too.

Comment: Is this a simulator running?

Comment: @LalKrishna No,run on iPhone 5 with iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put Pods into .gitignore,then pod install,solved the problem.